# Common object definitions - PayPal REST API - What is it? How can it be used?

Tags: api, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am analysing PayPal REST API - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/

I noticed within individual resources for e.g. Orders, there are Common Object Definition.
Can someone please explain what these are ? and how they can be used during making requests to sandbox PayPal API?

To explain further - Orders do not lay out **Order line items** data within response object.
However within Orders' Common Object Definitions - there is **Item** available - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-item

Would this mean the data is available via the common object definition? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the documentation for a request, some keys are of type 'object', meaning they are more than just a string -- they contain subkeys.

You can click next to that key name to view the object definition. That's what the common object definitions are; they can be referenced from more than one place in the documentation, e.g. different API requests or responses.